# Is there anyway to create a girdview inside a dropdown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm new in flutter.
As the title , I'm trying to create a view like this bottom.
I know that DropDownButton can create a list under to select , but what if I need the list to be gridview?
[image: GridViewDropDown]

I have tried using DropDownButton. But I didn't find a place to change the list to gridview list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom  rows and columns  or just use Table widget  check it here [Table widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

Comment: You mean I need to customize all that by myself. Is there any plugin or other widgets that can do the trick?

Comment: Use table widget table its already built for you, just provide the values check the flutter team video in the link above

Comment: Ah I see , are you saying that I can just put the row under DropdownMenuItem and use TextButton in Rows so I can detect the click?